# Mutual Certificate Based Authentication ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, openssl

I have been trying to implement Certificate based Authentication on both Client Side and Server Side.
I have gone through almost all StackOverflow questions asked but nothing was useful for me.

Some we based on

- loading Certificate from the System Path (not my Scenario)
- Some were to get from the API Request (might be helpful for me)

By getting the certificate from api request case. i am getting empty list of certificates

```
RequestContext.ClientCertificate
```

and when i change the WebConfig Key Settings to below

```
<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert,SslRequireCert"/>
```

i am gettting below error

> HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden The page you are attempting to access
>   requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client
>   certificate that the Web server recognizes.

And also I have plenty of certificates available in the client system, not even single Certificate is coming in request.

Any help would be appreciated